# Highcharts: Shifting the chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I shift the chart to left to avoid collide between candlesticks and number lables and make it more readable?
[image: shifting the chart]

Comment: Maybe better is setting [offset](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.offset) for yAxis